# Material-ui Text Field component not looking and not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

[image]

```js
// React
import { useState } from 'react'

// Material ui
import { TextField, makeStyles, Button, Typography } from '@material-ui/core'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  loginInput: {
    width: "100%",
    marginTop: 15,
  },
  button: {
    width: "100%",
    marginTop: 15
  }
})

const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
  const [passwordConfirmation, setPasswordConfirmation] = useState("")

  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <div className="form">
      <form className="login-form">
        <TextField label="Email" onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} value={email} required type="email" variant="outlined" color="primary" className={classes.loginInput} />
        <TextField label="Password" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} value={password} required type="password" variant="outlined" className={classes.loginInput} />
        <TextField label="Password Confirmation" onChange={e => setPasswordConfirmation(e.target.value)} value={passwordConfirmation} required type="password" variant="outlined" color="primary" className={classes.loginInput} />
        <Button type="submit" variant="contained" className={classes.button}><Typography>Login</Typography></Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

This is my code for my login component i cannot find any issues but it is not rendering the input components properly as shown in the picture, So please help me to find what is wrong here.

Comment: If you make a login form like this, you cant check proper data before submit, you should use `formik` or something with more logic, also you didn't need pass `className="form"`? did you use bootstrap as well? remove them and check results.

Comment: This is not a fully functional login form, i thought that it would be great if i create stylings first and create the functionalities, but before adding features to it something messed up with the material ui components also i am not using bootstrap and className="form" is my own css style to center the form

Comment: for centering and size use `<Grid/>` and let material UI take care of resizing and query.

Comment: but my problem is not center the form as it is easy to do. See the image the components are looking weird that is what i am worrying about

Comment: if i remove the className="form", will these weird things get stopped???

Comment: can you specifically point out what is the weird part of this code/form? I mean what exactly is the issue... because the sandbox code is looking fine and working as expected

Comment: I mean the unexpected arrows and improper way of rendering of the label as shown in the image above as weird things

Comment: can you post the css code of classes `form` and `login-form`. bcoz I've created a separate sandbox of your given code and it is working perfectly... check here:-  https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-grothendieck-epumw